# select from one database to update another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to update the a table in sql server from one database to another and i was wondering how to do that with

here is my example

```
UPDATE [Logix].[sysdba].[TICKET] (
    STATUSCODE) 
SELECT TICKETID, GM_NUMBER, STATUSCODE
 FROM [Logix_Dev].[sysdba].[TICKET]
 where GM_NUMBER <> ''
```

but i feel like this is the wrong syntax...basically what i want to do is select all the records from the TICKET table in the Logix_Dev database and update the statuscode on the Logix database where the TICKETID match....

Comment: Are the databases on the same instance of SQL Server?

Comment: @Tamer - then my answer should work out for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use aliases to make your life easier (same instance):

```
UPDATE l
SET l.STATUSCODE=s.someVal
FROM Logix.sysdba.Ticket l
INNER JOIN Logix_dev.sysdba.ticket s
ON s.ID = l.ID
```

Of course you will need to replace s.ID and l.ID with the appropriate columns (TicketID ?):

```
UPDATE l 
SET l.STATUSCODE=s.STATUSCODE 
FROM Logix.sysdba.Ticket l 
INNER JOIN Logix_dev.sysdba.ticket s 
ON s.TicketID = l.TicketID 
WHERE s.GM_NUMBER = ''
```

If they are on the same instance then do not need two dots (..).  If it is a linked server or on another instance you need two dots (..):

Linked server:

```
UPDATE l
SET l.STATUSCODE=s.someVal
FROM Logix.sysdba.Ticket l
INNER JOIN Logix_dev..sysdba.ticket s
ON s.ID = l.ID
```

Comment: You forgot `WHERE s.GM_NUMBER <> ''`

Comment: @Drackir - Teach a man to fish - don't give them the fish.  That's just an addition.

Comment: @misha - no one copied your answer, the post does not mention whether the op is using a linked server or not.  SO uses logging to show when answers / edits and posts where made.  I posted an answer 3 minutes before you, so I'd question who was copying.  The detail of double dot is NOT in the question at all.

Comment: question....i love this query...it works great but i totally dont understand how it works when there is no select clause at all..how is that possible and can you please walk through the way it works..thanks again

Comment: @Tamer - It's not a `select` statement its an `update` statement.  Of course it works because you are basically stating `Update my table Ticket and set the status code to someVal as long as the join condition is met` it really is that simple.

Comment: It wouldn't harm to be explicit and specify the name of the table in full in case of the linked server (I mean, specify the DB name too), but otherwise +1.

Comment: @Tamer You might want to take a look at the description of [`FROM <table_source>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx). You should note that not all Databases allow the UPDATE/FROM syntax this way

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
UPDATE [Logix].[sysdba].[TICKET] (
    STATUSCODE) 
SELECT TICKETID, GM_NUMBER, STATUSCODE
 FROM [Logix_Dev]..[sysdba].[TICKET]
 where GM_NUMBER <> ''
```

Notice the **double dot** after the DB name.

Comment: double dot is only needed if its a linked server or another instance.

Comment: Actually the double dot is after the *server* name in your query, not after the *DB* name. Also, you've got the syntax wrong.

Comment: Oops, sorry, it's not you, it's the OP who's got the syntax wrong. But you shouldn't have blindly copied it, I think.